# R exact and partial matching in multiple columns

Tags: r

Experts in R.

I have two dataframes.

dataframe one:

```
df1 <- c("xx", "bb", "zz")
```

dataframe two:

```
df2 <- data.frame(A=c("xx", "be", "zz", "jj"), B=c("xyx, uu, zz", "uu, zbbz, zbz, ccc", "cc, zzx", "ddd"), C=c("bbbb", "yyy", "xxq", "ooo"), D=c("ooo", "yyy", "ccc", "zoz"))
```

Thus, df2 is as follows:

```
   A                  B    C   D
1 xx        xyx, uu, zz bbbb ooo
2 be uu, zbbz, zbz, ccc  yyy yyy
3 zz            cc, zzx  xxq ccc
4 jj                ddd  ooo zoz
```

I want to match x with y to get a new dataframe. Looking at Stackoverflow answers, I learned how to do some exact matching. In the current situation though, I want to do both exact match and partial match. It seems to me that "grep" may help, but I cannot get it to work for my case yet, please kindly help.

In df1, I have to three terms for matching "xx", "bb" and "zz".  Instead of searching for exact xx, bb, zz in the df2.  I want to  check if these terms can be found in column A and B of df2, which may contain exact match and partial match.

For instance, I would consider

1. xx match row 1 (exact match with A1)
2. bb match both row 2 only (partial
   match with B2)
3. zz match both row 1
   and row 3 (partial match with B1 and
   exact match with A3, partial match
   with B3 too),
4. As zz match with two
   two items, I want to sort the one
   with exact match first in the final
   dataframe, i.e. row3 shown up first,
   row 1 shown up next.
5. While row 4 of
   df2 did not match with anythings in
   the table, so, it would not show up
   in the final dataframe.

Finally, I want to get a dataframe by added corresponding df2 to df1 as follows:

```
  V1   A                  B    C   D
1 xx   xx        xyx, uu, zz bbbb ooo
2 bb   be uu, zbbz, zbz, ccc  yyy yyy
3 zz   zz            cc, zzx  xxq ccc
4 zz   xx        xyx, uu, zz bbbb ooo
```

Is grep or sort can be used in this case?  Please instruct smarter way of doing this. Thanks.

Comment: For the first part of your problem what will be in the data frame results? Coordinates or the matched string?

Answer (score 2):

This should get you there:

```
dfrPerVal<-lapply(df1, function(dfrPartFor){
        whereFoundA<-grep(dfrPartFor, df2$A, fixed=TRUE)
        whereFoundB<-grep(dfrPartFor, df2$B, fixed=TRUE)
        retval<-cbind(1=dfrPartFor, df[union(whereFoundA, whereFoundB),]
        xmatch<-which((retval$A==dfrPartFor) | (retval$B==dfrPartFor))
        if(length(xmatch) > 0)
        {
            retval<-rbind(retval[xmatch, ], retval[-xmatch, ])
        }
        return(retval)
    })
finalResult<-do.call(rbind, dfrPerVal)
```

There are no doubt better solutions...